# XML xPath get parent attribute and children results in one query

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have this XML :

```
 <Parent>
  <Children name='RandomValueIdontKnow'>
   <x>1</x>
   <x>2</x>
   <x>3</x>
   <x>4</x>
  </Children>
 </Parent>
```

I want to get `Children`'s `name` attribute value **AND** all `x`'s values in one query

What i tried so far .. :

```
xpath("Children/@name|x");
```

but it only comes up with the `name` attribute value and ignores `x`'s values ..
I tried to remove `Parent` from the xml and do this query :

```
xpath("@name|x"); //grabs name's attribute value and all of the x's values
```

it worked fine, for some reason it stops when there's a parent or something.. that's kinda confusing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` aren't rootnodes, so you'll have to repeat `Children`:

```
"Children/@name|Children/x"
```

Comment: What if there are several kind of those nodes, how do i know what name belongs to the resulted x's ? i mean.. is there a way to make that @name contain the x's in an array in the result ?

Comment: Nope. There's afaik no hierarchy like that, and how would an attribute contains real nodes (BTW: Daniel's answer is better, I'd accept that one...).

Comment: Although, another option could just be to select `Children[@name]`, and just retrieving the name & `x` nodes in that `Children` node, keeps everything nice & tidy.

Answer (score 1):

For XPath 1.0, try:

```
(/*/Children/@name|/*/Children/x)
```

For XPath 2.0, try:

```
/*/Children/(@name|x)
```